# Flask with HBase

Tags: python, hadoop, solr, flask, hbase

I am designing an API service for a fairly big data set. 
The data is currently stored in HDFS and we(BAs) usually query it from Hive. In the end, we have several tables that we want to expose to customers in the format of API, the API might also be used in the future to backup frontend app.

I am a Python programmer and I have used Flask before. However, what is the correct technology combo to build an API service that can scale well?

I heard some people mentioned "HBase + Solr Cloud" will be the solution. 
Any suggestion will be super helpful and I will delete this post if think this is not programing related.

(I am also open to PaaS, IaaS like AWS, googlecloud if they actually have a decent package already.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking into this as well.

I've found the "happybase" python module. That should help connecting Python Flask with HBase.